# Laravel 5.2, friendship model, how to add correctly in the User model?

Tags: laravel

I try to implement [this solution](https://github.com/hootlex/laravel-friendships) to Laravel 5.2,
I did all installation steps, but I can't get it to work, and for example I want to use `$user->getFriends();`, I can use it directly from view or only from constructor?
And where I must setup a model, on User.php or I can do it in Friend.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add the `Friendable` trait to your `User` model.

```
use Hootlex\Friendships\Traits\Friendable;
class User extends Model
{
    use Friendable;
    ...
}
```

Then, if you've installed everything and migrated the database, you can access friendships like below:

```
$user = new User::find(1);
$recipient = new User::find(2);
// both `$user` and `$recipient` are instances of your `User` model
// no `Friend` model needed.


$user->befriend($recipient);
// now `$user` has just friended `$recipient` 
// you should be able to access all the methods provided by the trait.
```